# Howto use properly left join and count in a select statement

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have a query as below.

In OrderDetails table there is a column that indicates how many rows are successfully processed. What I want to achieve is to get success rows count per order.

This query is throwing exception "The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'".

What I should do to fix the query?

```
var query = dbContext.Set<Orders>()
.Include(x => x.Users)
.Include(x => x.Branches)
.GroupJoin(dbContext.Set<OrderDetails>().Where(x => x.IsSuccess == true),
ma => ma.ID,
maR => maR.OrderId,
(ma, maR) => new { ma, maR })
.SelectMany(
    x => x.maR.DefaultIfEmpty()
    ,(x, y) => new
    {
        x.ma.ID,
        x.ma.StartedAt,
        x.ma.EndedAt,
        x.ma.TimeOfCreation,
        x.ma.Requester,
        RowsCount = x.ma.Rows.Count,
        Branch = x.ma.Branch
    }).GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.ID,
        x.StartedAt,
        x.EndedAt,
        x.TimeOfCreation,
        x.Requester,
        x.RowsCount,
        x.Branch
    }).Select((x, y) => new
    {
        x.Key.ID,
        x.Key.StartedAt,
        x.Key.EndedAt,
        x.Key.TimeOfCreation,
        x.Key.Requester,
        x.Key.RowsCount,
        x.Key.Branch,
        SuccessQty = x.Count()
    });

var theList = query.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Order table is the header table, order details table contains lines regarding the order. OrderDetails table may not contain any records which IsSuccess = true. I think this gives clear picture. If you have any other approach I'm open for suggestion.

Comment: Even if I write RowsCount = 0 it doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Use a navigation property `Order.OrderDetails`. In general, when working with EF you should hardly ever need hard-coded joins.