# Join 3 tables in SQL using Entity Framework and LINQ

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Trying to join 3 SQL tables with EF and LINQ, not sure how to write the right script. I know how to do it with 2 tables, but got a bit lost once a third table came into play.

I have 3 tables, the models look like that:

**User**:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

**UserName**:

```
public class UserName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public User User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

**UserNameValues**:

```
public class UserNameValues 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserNameId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; } = null!;
 
    public UserName UserName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I want to get the value from `UserNameValues`

```
where user.id = x and username.name = x
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (assuming a variable called `context` with a collection of `UserNameValues`):

```
context.UserNameValues.Where(unv => unv.UserName.Name == "juan" && unv.UserName.User.Id == x);
```

I personally dislike the SQL-like syntax and stopped using it a long time ago in favor of the method calls, precisely because it's confusing.

Comment: Last comment has no sense. Use query syntax when it is needed or you will start writing something ugly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74299828/10646316)